# ride robotframework 1.5.2.1 cant find option to create a new directory

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

The option to add a new directory in ride is not available, I've tried to re install the application multiple times with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a New Project with the option of being a Directory or a File. If you select Directory, it will be created with the Test Suite structure.